# Проблема с выборкой в jquery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, у меня проблема с выборкой переменной. Условия такова: Вытаскиваю и БД все контакты, у каждого контакта есть свои данные(емайл, телефон и т.д.)и внизу еще есть кнопка типа "Написать письмо" и скрытый инпут который я пытаюсь передать email адрес (чтоб PHP обработчик знал куда отправить письмо) через  jquery на модальное окно, вот конец php код:

```
<p><span ><a id='modal'  class='ta'  href='#dialog'>Контакт с агентом<a/></span></P>

                            <input id='emailTo1' type='hidden' value='%s'>
```

Далее, когда  пользователь нажимает кнопку "Написать письмо", открывается модальное окно с формой для отправки заявку и через jquery значения инпута на скрытый инпут открывшей форме, чтоб потом передать  это значения методом POST на php обработчику. Пробовал выбрать таким образом:

```
var mail = $('#emailTo1').val();
        $('#emailTo').val(mail);
```

//передаю значения к форму
    Но это показывает со всех форм один email т.е. самого первого контакта, как можно сделать так чтоб у когда нажимаешь на кнопку, на модальном окне показывал свою почту а не первого в списке? Подскажите

Comment: у вас id emailTo1 встречается более одного раза, что нарушает правило "id должен быть уникальным", плюс нужно больше разметки

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не подскажете как можно решить эту проблему, мне получается нужно выбрать именно ту значения который пользователь выбрал, а как это делать?

Comment: я же говорю, нужно больше разметки, по тому, что вы показали сложно определить структуру документа, чтобы можно было воспользоваться [Tree Traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно добавить атрибут **data** и писать в него электронный адрес.

HTML:

```
<p><span class='dialog' data='username@email.ru'>Контакт с агентом</span></P>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.dialog').click(function() {
  var mail = $(this).attr('data');
  $('#emailTo').val(mail)
});
```

Здесь убрана ссылка, а класс dialog при этом *выглядит* как ссылка:

```
.dialog {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #00f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00f;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Khvorostin верно ответил, хотя и не полностью, но идею подал в нужном направлении.

Однако я хотел бы обратить внимание на одну деталь в постановке задачи у автора.

Автор генерирует список контактов, в результате чего у него получится список вроде:

```
<a href="" data="xxx@wyandex.ru">Контакт1</a>
<a href="" data="yyy@rgmail.com">Контакт2</a>
<a href="" data="zzz@drambler.ru">Контакт3</a>
<a href="" data="foo@fmail.ru">Контакт4</a>
<a href="" data="bar@sinbox.ru">Контакт5</a>
```

Обращаю внимание на то, что список почтовых адресов, которые будут использоваться для отправки сообщения, передается на клиентскую сторону. Это не есть хорошо по минимум двум причинам:

1. Ваш ресурс станет быстро популярным для сбора ящиков для спам-базы. Но, конечно, Ваши контакты не узнают кого нужно благодарить за большое количество нового спама.
2. С Вашего ресурса можно отправлять письма на любые почтовые ящики, просто передавая произвольный ящик Вашему скрипту отправки.

В связи с этим, рекомендую отсылать с dialog-окна не почтовый ящик адресата, а его идентификатор в базе данных. Поскольку Вы все равно отправляете почту со стороны сервера, ничто Вам не мешает перед отправкой вытащить из базы почтовый адрес адресата по его идентификатору.

Comment: Во, точно, попробую так, спасибо за подсказку!